# Python Dataframe Sum and Rank the Rows based on the group they belong

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

My df has USA states-related information. I want to rank the states based on its contribution.

My code:

```
df
   State  Value Year
0   FL     100   2012
1   CA     150   2013
2   MA      25   2014
3   FL     50    2014
4   CA     50    2015
5   MA     75    2016
```

Expected Answer: Compute state_capacity by summing state values from all years. Then Rank the States based on the state capacity

```
df
   State  Value Year   State_Capa.  Rank
0   FL     100   2012    150         2
1   CA     150   2013    200         1
2   MA     25    2014    100         3
3   FL     150    2014    200         2
4   CA     50    2015    200         1
5   MA     75    2016    100         3
```

My approach: I am able to compute the state capacity using groupby. I ran into NaN when mapped it to the df.

```
state_capacity = df[['State','Value']].groupby(['State']).sum()
df['State_Capa.'] = df['State'].map(dict(state_cap))
    df
       State  Value Year   State_Capa.  
    0   FL     100   2012    NaN        
    1   CA     150   2013    NaN         
    2   MA     25    2014    NaN         
    3   FL     50    2014    NaN         
    4   CA     50    2015    NaN         
    5   MA     75    2016    NaN
```

Comment: your question seems to have a problem. How state_cap for FL can be boh 150 and 200 in the second table?

Comment: @AminBa A typo. corrected now.

Comment: It is still the same. Another problem is that you cannot groupby and still have the year column. Because your grouping by value. By the way, check my answer to see if it is what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `transform` then `rank`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('State').Value.transform('sum').rank(method='dense',ascending=False)
Out[42]: 
0    2.0
1    1.0
2    3.0
3    2.0
4    1.0
5    3.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: A general question: If there is a gap in the column name, like `value 1` then we cannot use `df.value 1` right?

Comment: @Mainland then df['value 1']

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your question seems to have a problem. However, I guess this might be what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'state': ['FL', 'CA', 'MA', 'FL', 'CA', 'MA'],
    'value': [100, 150, 25, 50, 50, 75],
    'year': [2012, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2016]
})
```

returns:

```
    state   value   year
0   FL      100     2012
1   CA      150     2013
2   MA      25      2014
3   FL      50      2014
4   CA      50      2015
5   MA      75      2016
```

and

```
groupby_sum = df.groupby('state')['state', 'value'].sum()
groupby_sum['rank'] = groupby_sum['value'].rank()
groupby_sum.reset_index()
```

returns:

```
    state   value   rank
0   CA      200     3.0
1   FL      150     2.0
2   MA      100     1.0
```